# Let $K$ be a subgroup of $H$ of order 5. Prove that $N(K)\ge N(H)$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $525$ and suppose $G$ is not simple.  Then $G$ must have $15$ Sylow $7$-subgroups (of order $7$).  Let $H$ be such a subgroup.  Then $[G:N(H)] = 15$, where $N(H)$ is the normalizer of $H$ in $G$.  Thus $N(H)$ has order $35$, whence $N(H)$ is cyclic.

MY QUESTION:

> Let $K$ be a subgroup of $H$ of order $5$.  Prove that $N(K)\ge N(H)$.

Comment: Hint: A cyclic finite group of order $n$ has a unique subgroup of order $d$ for each positive integer divisor $d$ of $n.$

Comment: Is G supposed to be nonabelian?

Comment: Do you mean $K$ subgroup of $N_G(H)$?

Comment: The cyclic group of order 525 is not simple, but it has only a single Sylow 7-subgroup. Perhaps you need to correct some things.

Comment: I meant, K is a subgroup of N(H).  My error.

Comment: Got the problem - had a brain freeze.